# Using std::thread to call std::sort directly

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting, c++11

How can I make a thread execute `std::sort()` directly, without creating an intermediate function?

Something like:

```cpp
std::thread t1(std::sort, data.begin(), data.end());
```

My (playground!) idea is letting each thread sort half of the vector and then merge it:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Type your code here, or load an example.
void myfunc(std::vector<int>& data) {
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.begin() + data.size() / 2);
    return;
}

int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> data = { 1, 8, 123, 10, -3, 15, 2, 7 };
    std::thread t1(myfunc, std::ref(data)); // works
    //std::thread t1(std::sort, data.begin(), data.begin() + data.size() / 2); // doesn't
    std::sort(data.begin() + data.size() / 2, data.end());
    t1.join();
    std::inplace_merge(data.begin(), data.begin() + data.size() / 2, data.end());

    for (auto x : data)
        std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Compiler error, when using the commented line instead of the one above (I used an online code editor):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int>::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >)'
   16 | d t1(std::sort, data.begin(), data.begin() + data.size() / 2); // doesn't
      |                                                             ^

In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/thread:43,
                 from /tmp/bBJEjs0nrj.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:127:7: note: candidate: 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args, class> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)'
  127 |       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
      |       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:127:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/bBJEjs0nrj.cpp:16:75: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'
   16 | d t1(std::sort, data.begin(), data.begin() + data.size() / 2); // doesn't
      |                                                             ^

In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/thread:43,
                 from /tmp/bBJEjs0nrj.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:157:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)'
  157 |     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:157:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:121:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread()'
  121 |     thread() noexcept = default;
      |     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:121:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
```

Desired output:

```
-3,1,27,8,10,15,123
```

Comment: I would help you faster if you had posted a [mcve] with all required #include.

Comment: I am really curious what is the motivation to post an almost complete example, but remove all the includes. Is there some reason to it? or do you have a precompiled header and expect all others to use the same?

Comment: FWIW this [functionality is built in to C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) where the first parameter is an execution policy. So you wouldn't need to do this and it could take advantage of OS things like thread pools to reduce overhead which `std::thread` cannot.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number no motivation, but rather an oversight :)

Comment: sometimes the difference between "meh" and a good question is so small  ;)

Comment: Note to myself: only use Ctrl+A and not Mouse Select for copying ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most direct translation of the original code uses a template instantiation:

```
std::thread t1(std::sort<std::vector<int>::iterator>,
    data.begin(), data.end());
```

Comment: It's correct. Just wanted to post my answer, but you were first. https://godbolt.org/z/z4Kr8dd49

Comment: I like this more than mine.  One suggestion, change `std::sort<std::vector<int>::iterator>` to `std::sort<decltype(data)::iterator>` to "future proof" the code.

Comment: @273K -- thanks for the information. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I am always cautious with taking pointers to std functions. Afaik its only allowed when explicitly stated. Not sure what applies here.

Comment: @MSalters -- my usual approach is to not write `typename` and if the compiler complains add it. <g>

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are correct that it is only allowed if it is explicitly stated, and no, `std::sort` is not explicitly stated so.

Answer (score 5):

`std::sort()` is a function template, and as such cannot be passed as-is to a function that expects a concrete functor (a type that behaves like a function).  You need to either cast `std::sort` to the correct function pointer type, or else wrap it in some way that lets the compiler figure out which version of `std::sort()` you are trying to call.

The easiest way to deal with that is to use a lambda expression to wrap the call to `std::sort()` so that the compiler can do the template deduction for you.  That can look like this:

```
std::thread t1([&](){ std::sort(data.begin() + data.size() / 2, data.end()); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda:

```
    std::thread t1([&data](){std::sort(data.begin() + data.size() / 2, data.end());});
```

Comment: That creates an intermediate `operator()` member function. Lambda's are still C++ objects.